# Reducing vertical space between two sections of text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reduce the vertical space between two sections, however, being a knob at CSS doesn't help.  Using tables (heh) the spacing she is gone, but with CSS I'm pulling my hair out.

If you copy/paste the code below you'll notice the vertical spacing between "Link Heading" and "www.123.com" is different than that between "www.123.com" and "Some more text":

```
Link Heading...
www.123.com
Some more text...
```

Here's the skinny

```
<head>
<style>
body{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif}
.link{color:#0000cc}
.heading{float:left;font-size:1.2em;margin:0;font-weight:normal}
.result{font-size:0.850em;line-height:1em;margin-bottom:20px}
.site,.info{float:left;font-size:1em}
.info{color:#222234}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a class=link href='http://www.123.com/'>
        <span class=heading>Link Heading...</span>
    </a>
    <br>
    <div class=result>
        <span class=site>www.123.com</span>
        <br>
        <span class=info>Some more text...</span>
    </div>

<br>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr><td><a class=link href='http://www.123.com/'>Link Heading...</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>www.123.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some more text...</td></tr>
</table> 
</body>
```

Now I know the answer is going to be something obvious, but I can't see the forest for the friggin css trees anymore.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: Of course it is different, you don't use the same styles in the table

Comment: The style has nothing to do with it.  The float is just there from extracting from the larger file.  ie, this is just a snippet to make it easier to read/parse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use CSS `line-height:` or negativ `margin:` to change that vertical space
also be sure if you are using breaks `<br>` that their `height:` also changes the vertical space

Comment: That's it!  Thank so much:

`.result{font-size:0.850em;line-height:1em;margin:-4px 0 20px 0px}`

Answer (score 0):

It is because the table rows () has a height of 27 pixels.
If you set class to info in both and style .info {height: 27px; color:#222234}, they will be the same height as in the table.

```
<div class=result>
        <span class=info>www.123.com</span>
        <br>
        <span class=info>Some more text...</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting rid of your `<br>` tags, and using a [Block Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes).

From the related [Block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
>   vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical
>   distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin'
>   properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a
>   block formatting context collapse.

This means that block elements, such as `<div>` and `<p>` (among others) will *automatically* include a line break after them, and the space between them can be controlled with `margin`. As such, I'd change your code to look more like the following:

```
<body>
    <div class="heading">
        <a class=link href='http://www.123.com/'>Link Heading...</a>
    </div>
    <div class=result>
        <p class=site>www.123.com</p>
        <p class=info>Some more text...</p>
    </div>

    <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
        <tr><td><a class=link href='http://www.123.com/'>Link Heading...</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td>www.123.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Some more text...</td></tr>
    </table> 
</body>
```

A couple other nitpicks:

- Use quotes around your attribute values (`<p class="site">...</p>`)
- Don't use tables for layout (using tables for tabular data is okay)
- Proper indentation makes your code more readable

Comment: Thanks Ryan - the table was just for comparison purposes.  In fact, the whole snippet was copy/pasted and then edited/reduced for posting here.  Your link/comments about Block Element is exactly what I was looking for - even though @ggzone gave an alternative suggestion which worked (ie, I won't have to recode everything).

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a simple solution by putting everything and the same div and only applying a style the the link by using the "a".

```
<head>
<style>
body{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif}

.result{
    font-size:0.850em;
    line-height:1.2em;
    margin-bottom:20px
    }

.result a
{
    float:left;
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin:0;
    font-weight:normal
}

.result a:link
{
    color:#0000cc;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.result a:hover
{
    color: #1a0186;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class=result>
        <a href='http://www.123.com/'>Link Heading...</a><br>
        www.123.com <br>
        Some more text...
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice clean looking approach.